# How do I make this function iterable (getting indexerror)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, iterator

I am fairly new to python and coding in general.
I have a big data file that provides daily data for the period 2011-2018 for a number of stock tickers (300~).

The data is a .csv file with circa 150k rows and looks as follows (short example):

```
Date,Symbol,ShortExemptVolume,ShortVolume,TotalVolume
20110103,AAWW,0.0,28369,78113.0
20110103,AMD,0.0,3183556,8095093.0
20110103,AMRS,0.0,14196,18811.0
20110103,ARAY,0.0,31685,77976.0
20110103,ARCC,0.0,177208,423768.0
20110103,ASCMA,0.0,3930,26527.0
20110103,ATI,0.0,193772,301287.0
20110103,ATSG,0.0,23659,72965.0
20110103,AVID,0.0,7211,18896.0
20110103,BMRN,0.0,21740,213974.0
20110103,CAMP,0.0,2000,11401.0
20110103,CIEN,0.0,625165,1309490.0
20110103,COWN,0.0,3195,24293.0
20110103,CSV,0.0,6133,25394.0
```

I have a function that allows me to filter for a specific symbol and get 10 observations before and after a specified date (could be any date between 2011 and 2018).

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import urllib
import datetime

def get_data(issue_date, stock_ticker):
    df = pd.read_csv (r'D:\Project\Data\Short_Interest\exampledata.csv')
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%Y%m%d")
    d = df

    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    short = df.loc[df.Symbol.eq(stock_ticker)]
    # get the index of the row of interest
    ix = short[short.Date.eq(issue_date)].index[0]
    # get the item row for that row's index
    iloc_ix = short.index.get_loc(ix)
    # get the +/-1 iloc rows (+2 because that is how slices work), basically +1 and -1 trading days
    short_data = short.iloc[iloc_ix-10: iloc_ix+11]
    return [short_data]
```

I want to create a script that iterates a list of 'issue_dates' and 'stock_tickers'. The list (a .csv) looks as following:

```
ARAY,07/08/2017
ARAY,24/04/2014
ACETQ,16/11/2015
ACETQ,16/11/2015
NVLNA,15/08/2014
ATSG,29/09/2017
ATI,24/05/2016
MDRX,18/06/2013
MDRX,18/06/2013
AMAGX,10/05/2017
AMAGX,14/02/2014
AMD,14/09/2016
```

To break down my problem and question I would like to know how to do the following:

First, how do I load the inputs?

Second, how do I call the function on each input?

And last, how do I accumulate all the function returns in one dataframe?

Comment: You want to get a date range like you are doing now except for more than one symbol value? With the same date for all symbols or different dates for each symbol?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @wii I want to get it for more than one symbol and with different dates for each symbol. For example: 'ARAY' + '2011-01-08' and 'CAPM' + '2013-02-02' etc.

Comment: @wii But to make it more clear, the list I want to use is a list of rows (see main post, edited it an example)

Comment: But which part are you having trouble with? Loading the inputs? Calling the function on each input? Accumulating all of the function return values?

Comment: From loading the inputs (as it requires iterating row per row), to calling the function for each input. I haven't even looked into the accumulation of all the function return values yet, but it is an unknown for me so far. So basically making the function work with a script

Answer (score 0):

To load the *inputs* and call the function for each row; iterate over the csv file and pass each row's values to the function and accumulate the resulting `Series`in a list.

I modified your function a bit: removed the DataFrame creation so it is only done once and added a `try/except` block to account for missing dates or tickers (your example data didn't match up too well). The dates in the second csv look like they are `day/month/year` so I converted them for that format.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime, csv

def get_data(df, issue_date, stock_ticker):
    '''Return a Series for the ticker centered on the issue date.

    '''
    short = df.loc[df.Symbol.eq(stock_ticker)]
    # get the index of the row of interest
    try:
        ix = short[short.Date.eq(issue_date)].index[0]
        # get the item row for that row's index
        iloc_ix = short.index.get_loc(ix)
        # get the +/-1 iloc rows (+2 because that is how slices work), basically +1 and -1 trading days
        short_data = short.iloc[iloc_ix-10: iloc_ix+11]
    except IndexError:
        msg = f'no data for {stock_ticker} on {issue_date}'
        #log.info(msg)
        print(msg)
        short_data = None
    return short_data

df = pd.read_csv (datafile)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%Y%m%d")

results = []
with open('issues.csv') as issues:
    for ticker,date in csv.reader(issues):
        day,month,year = map(int,date.split('/'))
    #    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, r'%d/%m/%Y')
        date = datetime.date(year,month,day)
        s = get_data(df,date,ticker)
        results.append(s)
    #    print(s)
```

---

Creating a single DataFrame or table for all that info may be problematic especially since the date ranges are all different. Probably should ask a separate question regarding that. Its [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should probably just include a few minimal Pandas Series with a couple of different date ranges and tickers.